# When I build next js application and locally serve it data that is fetch form external api is got undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[I don't get data from external API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXFYW.png)

when I run it locally it works fine but when I build the next js application and run the build file data from external API got undefined in the console it shows the error like this --framework-3671d8951bf44e4e.js:9 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings._

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.